# $location not redirecting to the page

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to redirect to another page in my ionic app but stuck at this point. I see in console that my current path is what I want but I am not really on that page here is may code

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) {
    $ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);

    $stateProvider.state('homepage', {
        url: '/homepage',
        templateUrl: 'templates/homepage.html',
        controller: 'MapController'
        })

    .state('hotel', {
        url: '/hotel',
        templateUrl: 'templates/hotel.html',
        controller: 'HotelController'
    })
})
```

**Controller**

```
.controller('MapController', function($scope, $location, customservice) {
    $scope.fa = function(a) { 
        customservice.hotel_name =  {hotelName: a.innerHTML}
        console.log($location.path()) // prints /homepage
        $location.path('/hotel');
        console.log($location.path()) // print /hotel but still on same page
    }
});
```

Comment: Why don't you use $location.url() instead?

Comment: still getting same result

Comment: Sam, inject $state and use $state.go() to transition between your states, see if that works.

Comment: Don't know if it is why it failed, but you missed several `;` in your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know how and why but wrapping it under $timeout did the job for me

Comment: It should works **without** `$timeout`. It is a bad practice.

Answer (score 3):

The $location service allows you to change only the URL; some time it dones not reload/redirect page. Can you try $window.location.href or $state.go(), instead of $location.path(). May be it will work.

Answer (score 0):

It's very confusing thing. $location only changes url without reload.
You should write like this if you want to redirect.

```
$window.location.href = "http://www.google.com"
```

Please refer [Angulardoc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

```
When should I use $location?

Any time your application needs to react to a change in the current URL or if you want to change the current URL in the browser.
What does it not do?

It does not cause a full page reload when the browser URL is changed. To reload the page after changing the URL, use the lower-level API, $window.location.href
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
angular.module('windowExample', [])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {
    $window.location.href = '/hotel.html';
  };
}]);
```